# VIF calculation in python statsmodel

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

The code for calculating VIF in statsmodel is below:

```
k_vars = exog.shape[1]
x_i = exog[:, exog_idx]
mask = np.arange(k_vars) != exog_idx
x_noti = exog[:, mask]
r_squared_i = OLS(x_i, x_noti).fit().rsquared   ## NO INTERCEPT
vif = 1. / (1. - r_squared_i)
```

When fitting, it does not include an intercept. It seems intercept should be included according to "Introductory Econometrics (6ed)" by Wooldridge: "... R-squared from regressing Xj on all other independent variables (**and including an intercept**)."

Is statmodels wrong? Is there another package I can cross check? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong". This assumes that `exog` is from a regression model that includes a constant, if the user wanted one. See several related issues on statsmodels github. IIRC, you can compare the results to SAS and Stata.

Comment: Yes thank you. Answer updated.

Comment: Related: [scikit-learn & statsmodels - which R-squared is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using statsmodels, always be mindful of adding constant (which is necessary in this case); quoting from the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html):

> An intercept is not included by default and should be added by the user. See `statsmodels.tools.add_constant`.

Reference from MATLAB:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-ii-collinearity-and-estimator-variance.html

Answer (score 0):

In a traditional matrix formulation of the linear regression, the X-matrix always has a column vector of 1's in the first position - without this, we would get a regression through the origin , i.e. without an intercept term. I came across this question while looking for VIFs in statsmodels.