# How to find the equation from linear regression model

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science, statsmodels

I have a dataset and I am running a linear model.

```
lm_4 = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train).fit()
print(lm_4.summary())
```

The parameters are let's say as below:

```
print(lm_4.params)
const              0.001389
area               0.309894
bathrooms          0.314420
```

Now to predict:

```
lm_4.predict(X_test_m1.iloc[[1]])
```

Now my doubt is how can I export this model or how can i convert this to an equation so that I can use it independently this model anywhere else.
What is the exact equation is generated by the model.

Something like:

```
y = cont * 0.001389 + area * 0.309894 + bathroom*0.3144 + c
```

I am new to this. Any lead appreciated.

Comment: Please include explicitly your *imports*; plus, since as it seems you are using `statsmodels`, please remove the `scikit-learn` tag.

Comment: Keep in mind that, by default, statsmodels will **not** include a constant (intercept) term in the model; see answer in [scikit-learn & statsmodels - which R-squared is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898).

Comment: Your equation is indeed as you say, without the `c` term here; what exactly is your question/requirement? How to get such an equation programmatically? And if yes, in what form?

Comment: @desertnaut I want one final equation.I need to get the liner equation which is generated by the model.

Comment: In *what form*?? A string would be OK?

Comment: yes .It should be fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
y = []

for i in range(len(X_train)):
    y.append(X_train.area[i] * 0.309894 + X_train.bathroom[i] * 0.314420 + 0.001389)

print(y)
```

this is your equation

y = X_train.area * 0.309894 + X_train.bathroom * 0.314420 + 0.001389