# RandomForestRegressor model evaluation?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I am new to Machine-learning and trying to understand the correct and suitable evaluation for RandomForestRegressor. I have mentioned below Regression metrics and understood these concepts.

I am not sure that  Which metrics I can use the  for RandomForestRegressor's evaluation. Can I use r2_score all the time after prediction ?

I am using sklearn packages.

```
Regression metrics
See the Regression metrics section of the user guide for further details.

metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)    Explained variance regression score function
metrics.max_error(y_true, y_pred)   max_error metric calculates the maximum residual error.
metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred) Mean absolute error regression loss
metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred[, …]) Mean squared error regression loss
metrics.mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred)  Mean squared logarithmic error regression loss
metrics.median_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)   Median absolute error regression loss
metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred[, …])   R^2 (coefficient of determination) regression score function.
```

Comment: The metrics you mentioned do not depend on the model used. Think about it like accuracy for classification. where ever you've got predictions from, does not affect calculting how accurate they are.

Comment: sorry, I am not able to catch your point, since I am new to this area. it will be great if you provide more information with example. thanks for clarification.