# How much difference between training and test error is considered suitable?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, evaluation

I am working on regression problem and i used ad-boost with decision tree for regression and r^2 as evaluation measure. I want to know how much difference between training  r^2 and testing r^2 is considered suitable. I have training r^2 is **0.9438**  and testing r^2 is **0.877**. Is it over-fitting  or good?.I just want to know ***exactly*** how much difference between training and testing is *acceptable* or *suitable*?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your question.

To start with, r^2 is certainly **not** recommended as a performance evaluation measure for *predictive* problems; quoting from my own answer in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898):

> the whole R-squared concept comes in fact directly from the world of statistics, where the emphasis is on *interpretative* models, and it has little use in machine learning contexts, where the emphasis is clearly on *predictive* models; at least AFAIK, and beyond some very introductory courses, I have never (I mean *never*...) seen a predictive modeling problem where the R-squared is used for any kind of performance assessment; neither it's an accident that popular *machine learning* introductions, such as Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) at Coursera, do not even bother to mention it. And, as noted in the [Github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5570) above (emphasis added):
>
> > In particular when using a **test** set, it's a bit unclear to me what the R^2 means.
>
> with which I certainly concur.

Second:

> I have training r^2 is 0.9438 and testing r^2 is 0.877. Is it over-fitting or good?

A difference between a training and a test score by itself does **not** signify overfitting. This is just the **generalization gap**, i.e. the *expected* gap in the performance between the training and validation sets; quoting from a recent [blog post by Google AI](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html):

> An important concept for understanding generalization is the *generalization gap*, i.e., the difference between a model’s performance on training data and its performance on unseen data drawn from the same distribution.

The telltale **signature** of overfitting is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image]

(image adapted from the [Wikipedia entry on overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) - diferent things may lie in the horizontal axis, e.g. here the number of boosted trees)

> I just want to know ***exactly*** how much difference between training and testing is *acceptable* or *suitable*?

There is no general answer to this question; everything depends on the details of your data and the *business* problem you are trying to solve.