# Why is Sklearn R-squared different from that of statsmodels when fit_intercept=False?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am performing linear regression using Sklearn and statsmodels.

I know that Sklearn and statsmodels produce the same result. As shown below, Sklearn and statsmodels made the same result, but the results were different even though the coefficients were the same when the intercept is zero using `fit_intercept=False` in Sklearn.

Can you explain the reason? Or give me any method when I use `fit_intercept=False` in Sklearn.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# dummy data:
y = np.array([1,3,4,5,2,3,4])
X = np.array(range(1,8)).reshape(-1,1) # reshape to column

# intercept is not zero : the result are the same
# scikit-learn:
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X,y)
print(lr.score(X,y))
# 0.16118421052631582

# statsmodels
X_ = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y,X_)
results = model.fit()
print(results.rsquared)
# 0.16118421052631582

# intercept is zero : the result are different
# scikit-learn:
lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(X,y)
print(lr.score(X,y))
# -0.4309210526315792

# statsmodels
model = sm.OLS(y,X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.rsquared)
# 0.8058035714285714
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inconsistency is due to the fact that `statsmodels` uses different formulas to calculate the R-squared depending on whether the model includes an intercept or not. If the intercept is included, `statsmodels` divides the sum of squared residuals by the centered total sum of squares, while if the intercept is not included, `statsmodels` divides the sum of squared residuals by the uncentered total sum of squares. This means that `statsmodels` uses the following formula to calculate the R-squared, which can be found in the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.rsquared.html):

```py
import numpy as np

def rsquared(y_true, y_pred, fit_intercept=True):
    '''
    Statsmodels R-squared, see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.rsquared.html.
    '''
    if fit_intercept:
        return 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((y_true - np.mean(y_true)) ** 2)
    else:
        return 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum(y_true ** 2)
```

On the other hand, `sklearn` always uses the centered total sum of squares at the denominator, regardless of whether the intercept is actually included in the model or not (i.e. regardless of whether `fit_intercept=True` or `fit_intercept=False`). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618898/11989081).

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def rsquared(y_true, y_pred, fit_intercept=True):
    '''
    Statsmodels R-squared, see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.rsquared.html.
    '''
    if fit_intercept:
        return 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((y_true - np.mean(y_true)) ** 2)
    else:
        return 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum(y_true ** 2)

# dummy data:
y = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4])
X = np.array(range(1, 8)).reshape(-1, 1) # reshape to column

# intercept is not zero: the result are the same
# scikit-learn:
lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
lr.fit(X, y)
print(lr.score(X, y))
# 0.16118421052631582
print(rsquared(y, lr.predict(X), fit_intercept=True))
# 0.16118421052631582

# statsmodels
X_ = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X_)
results = model.fit()
print(results.rsquared)
# 0.16118421052631582
print(rsquared(y, results.fittedvalues, fit_intercept=True))
# 0.16118421052631593

# intercept is zero: the result are different
# scikit-learn:
lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(X, y)
print(lr.score(X, y))
# -0.4309210526315792
print(rsquared(y, lr.predict(X), fit_intercept=True))
# -0.4309210526315792
print(rsquared(y, lr.predict(X), fit_intercept=False))
# 0.8058035714285714

# statsmodels
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.rsquared)
# 0.8058035714285714
print(rsquared(y, results.fittedvalues, fit_intercept=False))
# 0.8058035714285714
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to my answer; but I think you have done a much better job here in explaining this particular case (i.e. both models fitted w/o intercept) than me, so I have updated my answer to link here, too. Cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks :) I realized only later (after I posted my answer) that the code included in the question was actually taken directly from your answer, so it should have probably been linked there in the first place.

Comment: Ooops... I hadn't noticed *that*! :) You are right, OP should have linked there themselves, if not for anything else but to explain why the particular case remained not well-explained.